# Browserify/JavaScript, otherjs.myfunction is not a function()

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm trying to make something in JS and using browserify to use other JS files in my main code. I know I have node and browserify installed correctly because I can enter "browserify example.js -o bundle.js" in the terminal and run his code just fine.

I finally just added my function (soundoff()) to his system.js code below and tried calling it the same way he called the functions in this file in the second code snippet...

```
    module.exports = (function (){
  var _final = "",
      DEFAULT_STEP = 15,
      DEFAULT_TURN = Math.PI / 4;



  /* Initializes an L-System using the supplied
   * axiom, rules, and number of iterations
   * params:
   * - axiom: the starting string
   * - rules: the array of rules as string -> string
   *   key/value pairs (i.e. ["key", "value"]
   * - iterations: the number of iterations to carry out
   */
  function lsystem(axiom, rules, iterations) {
    _final = axiom;

    for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      _final = apply(_final, rules);
    }

    return _final;
  }

  function soundoff(done) {
    return done;
  }
```

You see below here I'm calling it the same way he's calling other functions from the ls reference/function/module but I still get **"Uncaught TypeError: ls.soundoff is not a function"**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var ls = require('./lsystem.js');

  var wonk = ls.soundoff("wonk!");

  // Set up the algae demo
  var aIter = document.getElementById("algae-iterations"),
      aOut = document.getElementById("algae-output");
  aOut.value = ls.algae(0);
  aIter.onchange = function() {
    aOut.value = ls.algae(aIter.value);
  }
```

Without calling this function it works perfectly. Those aren't the whole code files but I know everything else if fine since they work, I just can't figure out why I can't have a function I put in like that and call it...

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

That wont work. Because soundoff is a function within lsystem function, which means soundoff is not accessible as a property.

If you can change your lsystem to export an Object and do this, it will work.

```
module.exports = {

 soundoff : function(done){
    return done;
}
}
```

Edit :

**Method 1:**

*file1.js*

```
module.exports = (function func(){

   return {

      soundoff : function(done){
           return done;
      }
    } 
});
```

*file2.js*

```
var func = require('file1');
var obj = func();
obj.soundoff('wonk');
```

**Method 2.**

*file1.js*

```
module.exports = {

 soundoff : function(done){
    return done;
}
}
```

*file2.js*

```
var obj = require('file1');
obj.soundoff('wonk');
```

**Method: 3**

There are other dirty ways where you could, use the *this* property in conjunction with **Function.prototype.call**, but I would advise you not to go for it. Do not use it, like, ever. Highly volatile.

*file1.js*

```
module.exports = (function func(){

      this.soundoff = function(done){
             return done;

         }

 });
```

*file2.js*

```
var func = require('file1');
func.call(func);
func.soundoff('wonk');
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the solution, but I don't understand how he's calling other ones, like algae with just ls.algae(param) in that first code snippet which calls this function:
        function algae(iterations) {
        return lsystem("A", [["A","AB"],["B","A"]], iterations);
       }

Comment: Can you share the link to the original system.js file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xh4aaMJr

^ here's the original sans my function soundoff() thing which uses the same syntax and is in the same code blocks as the other functions that the main file, example.js uses

http://pastebin.com/d8hW2crF

and I'm just browserifying it this way

>browserify example.js -o bundle.js

and everything works perfect except what I added. I'm now armed with your workaround but I want to understand how it's working

Comment: O MAN I get it now :) I changed it to

    var wonk = function() {
         ls.soundoff("wonk!");
       }

and it works now... the different syntax in your answer was throwing me off and i get it now... you can have other functions use the module but you can't access it like it's just in your code.

Thanks so much :) :) :)